# Viewing Adobe pdf file's first page as a thumbnail on windows 7 explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, adobe-reader

I'm using windows 7 64-bit. I installed Adobe CS6, and Adobe Acrobat X Pro. There was a problem with viewing first page of pdf file as thumbnail. I couldn't find official solution. Then I tried several solutions I found on forums : (i.e. opened reader x preferences (crtl + k), go to "General" tab, click "Select Default PDF handler" button and choose Reader). First it worked, but only for pdf files on desktop, others worked just until first restart or gave mixed results. Is there any radical solution for this problem?

Comment: will this work for you ? http://www.ehow.com/how_6782183_enable-thumbnail-preview-pdf-files.html

Comment: @MAKZ. Thanks for advice, but that keys are already in my windows registry.

Comment: Did you check [Fixes for 64-bit Adobe Reader preview handler and thumbnails](http://www.pretentiousname.com/adobe_pdf_x64_fix/) already?

Comment: Even with the new Adobe Acrobat update this is still not fixed.

Comment: May 2014 Acrobat Reader Update and this problem is still not fixed. This should be reported so Adobe fixes this, here: https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform